# How to change CSS with our requirement

Tags: css

I am using sb-admin  project how to set CSSpage wrapper ... it shows small background. I don't know why.
please check

```
body {
    background-color: #000216;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
}

#page-wrapper {
    padding: 0 15px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #F4E8FF;
}
```

[image]

[image: image2]

Comment: Scroll down the selectors in your debug tool. It shows other styles that it inherits - might be there :)

Comment: thanks for your reply i don't understand whay you mean ? @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: @AddiKhan. He is telling you to use inspect element and check your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the colored background not expanding with the content...I would try adding `float:left` on the wrapper and page-wrapper selectors in your CSS.